# How to detect long click on Key pressed on dialer?

Tags: android, android-dialer

Please tell me how can i get the key value pressed in my app on dial pad  because i wanna perform some action on behalf that key value?

Comment: Unles you're writing a custom dialer, you can't.

Comment: you can check `Key code constant`.... from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

Comment: @Mohit I am sure this is related to softkeyboard only not dialer app

Comment: i have not used till....but it also provide `  KEYCODE_X` which might be checked in dialer pad